# Manager banned tests and Linux

Tags: manager, software-development, conflict, tech-industry, test

My manager demanded I stop writing tests and instead start using manual testing like before I joined the company. After I mentioned I couldn't find something using the package manager, they also threatened to ban Linux laptops because previous employees had problems with it, despite Linux never being an issue for me, I found what I need on the internet. I use [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and not only do I not enjoy writing code without it, I also find it unsafe to not include tests in a program.

Is banning tests and Linux a red flag, and how can I convince my manager to include tests? I've already tried to convince my manager that unit and integration tests are important but they think that writing tests slows down development. The previous employee in my position was fired only after two weeks because my manager wanted someone who could add tests to the code base and they were not satisfied with their tests or test writing capabilities.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148596/discussion-on-question-by-duzii2-manager-banned-tests-and-linux); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 22):

> Is banning tests and linux a red flag?

Personally, I would look elsewhere if the micromanaging is this nonsensical and destructive.

In addition, the flip-flopping from wanting tests to not wanting tests and firing people after 2 weeks of employment seems somewhat toxic.

Only you can evaluate whether these requirements or demands are in line with your career goals.

Perhaps you should turn the question around - what are the reasons (if any) to stay in this job?

Answer (score 9):

I agree their inconsistencies regarding tests are concerning:

> - they think that writing tests slows down development.
> - demanded I stop writing tests and instead start using manual testing like before I joined the company.
> - The previous employee in my position was fired only after two weeks because my manager wanted someone who could add tests to the code base
>   and they were not satisfied with their tests or test writing
>   capabilities.

They are making decisions regarding who to hire and who to fire based on testing requirements that they are unsure of.

I will disagree with how you are handling the operating system of choice:

> After I mentioned I couldn't find something using the package manager,
> they also threatened to ban Linux laptops because previous employees
> had problems with it, despite Linux never being an issue for me, I
> found what I need on the internet.

If this is a company owned laptop, then the company has 100% the right to dictate the OS being used on their machines.

I worked on a project where they did let some developers use Linux on their laptop. The issue was that they were always fighting the simple stuff: power point, email, calendars. There was always an excuse why they couldn't read the files others were producing. Or they would miss a meeting because their calendar didn't show the new time.

The red flag in your question regarding Linux isn't your choice of OS.

It doesn't matter if you are on Linux or windows, letting everybody install stuff on their machine is dangerous. If a employee can download something from the internet and install it without a defined procedure the company IT infrastructure is at risk. Are you keeping up with all the patches? Are you running all the required security scans? Are you running with root privileges because it is simpler?

Comment: At my old job it was exactly like this. Some engineers wanted Linux or Mac notebooks for the life of it. Even tough it made little sense. Because we would all use Intellij and our product would be deployed on windows machines. Them wanting Linux notebooks was entirely ideological driven. I can relate to some degree because I used to be a hardcore Linux fanboy myself when I was younger. But sometimes you just have to make a management decision to stop these kind of ideological nonsense to increase productivity.

Comment: @seg This may be nothing to do with ideology at all. Even in your case, while IntelliJ may be pretty much the same on different platforms, I'd be surprised if your engineers don't also use a web browser, chat app, text editor, database client, videoconferencing app, VPN or other connectivity manager, or command-line tools. And while there are examples of all those for most platforms, the details can vary very significantly — and familiarity and comfort can make a significant difference to productivity and morale.

Comment: @gidds all these tools you listed are usually company demanded. Which means they will usually run a lot better on the OS of choice by the company. That's exactly one of the main problems of people using their os of choice they usually also start using unofficial chat apps etc. This all creates a lot of troubles. There are off course sometimes special circumstances. For example I used to administer red hat servers for a living and before there was WSL having a *nix notebook was a real advantage. Nowadays you can just do almost everything in WSL even starting X11 apps.

Comment: > "If a employee can download something from the internet and install it without a defined procedure the company IT infrastructure is at risk".  I can see this for regular employees - but devs need to be able to install their software of choice and shouldn't need a defined procedure.

Comment: @aaaaaa. When I was a developer I thought so to, but the number of times giving developers that power in situations where it wasn't necessary led to problems: viruses, code that could only compile on some machines, heisenbugs.

Comment: @seg I switched from Windows to Linux at my workplace because the former became excessively irritating to use for me (even if other colleagues are still using Windows). It doesn't mean that I couldn't do the job on Windows, but that the level of comfort was pretty low. Of course, if I was told to work on something that requires a Windows environment and was given a Linux OS, I would switch to Windows. In the end, I don't see any disadvantage of picking your preferred OS if there is no requirement whatsoever.

Comment: @aaaaaa the defined procedure can be "software should be installed through the official package manager for language X or IT-supported operating system Y" I realize there are places that take that to a pathological extreme of "submit this form in triplicate and wait 6 weeks for processing before running sudo apt install for a simple tool critical to your job" but it doesn't *always* mean that.

Comment: I think I mentioned to my manager that I couldn't find a an outlook client on Linux and that's when they made the threat. I use outlook on the browser.

Answer (score 7):

> Is banning tests and linux a red flag

No, their company, their rules. There is many valid reasons to ban Linux, and many valid reasons not to, but it's not your decision to make. Your decision is whether working conditions are ok or not on your terms, not to make the working conditions.

> The previous employee in my position was fired only after two weeks

This, coupled with the troubles you are having communicating professionally with your manager is a red flag, it means they're happy to scapegoat new employees and fire them.

Answer (score 4):

#### Companies get to decide how their employees get work done.

Clearly they value testing, the previous employee was fired because of it.  Your development process needs to match how the rest of the employees do it, there isn't really a place for your unique methods no matter how good your methods are. This is a standardization thing - your half-finished code should be able to be picked up by someone else at any point.

As to not allowing Linux, most companies past a certain size want standard supportable workstations.  Maybe you can support your own Linux box, but not everyone can, and managing exceptions is likely seen as having even less value.  This is not an unreasonable request by an employer.

If these things are important to you then you will probably be more comfortable at a company who either sets their processes like you would or who doesn't have any processes at all.  Most people find working at the latter to be very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

- Banning (automated) tests - Red flag
- Banning Linux - no flag
- Demanding manual tests - questionable.

As others already mentioned demanding (one) operating system has its logic - some tool and toolboxes are not 100% OS agnostic. As a result, different OSes in the team/company can strugle on bugs caused by different implemetations, different features etc. One system, one set of tools means much fewer sources of troubles.

If the manual tests can be easily automated, then banning the automation is a red flag. If the manual test are reasonable and automated tests are allowed then it is fine with me.

And as Kilisi wrote - their company, their rules. If you are okay with the rules, stay, if not, you are free to go at any time. And you don't need to include the company in your CV since you should list relevant work expiriences. If you do include and are asked about it you can answer "I realised their workflow / working culture was not compatible with my expectations." It also show your new possible employer that you won't waste their investments in you.

Comment: Good advice. If I don't include the company in my CV then how do I explain the employment gap? I've been working there for more than 6 months.

Comment: You can answer it as "unrelated work", or "promising offer that turned out in a poor choice", or even "work expirience I wouldn't like to talk about". You can be honest, but be careful not to talk dirty about the previous employer - this may, and more likely will, raise red flags. Keep neutral and objective, do not extrapolate and generalize.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own experiences, I've found that Linux desktops can be problematic in a workplace setting. Over the course of five years using Linux, I've encountered numerous instances where updates broke essential functionalities, requiring time-consuming fixes. This can be especially problematic in urgent situations, such as when production systems are down. I switched back to Mac and have found it to be a more stable environment for work.  I still use linux desktop for gaming, but I'm thinking of switching to windows for the same reason, the last time I tried to game for a few minutes my bluetooth stopped working and I haven't had time to fix it.

As for the question of automated testing, I can see where your boss is coming from. In certain organizational contexts, especially those constrained by time or budget, the priority often becomes delivering functional code above all else. While automated testing is undeniably beneficial for long-term code maintainability and speed of future development, these benefits are sometimes a luxury that not all projects or companies can afford. Manual testing or downstream QA can sometimes suffice, depending on the scale and complexity of the project. If the company or product grows to a point where testing becomes a bottleneck, that would be an appropriate time to re-evaluate the approach to include more automated testing.